# Clan Pro Font not applying for Russian language

Tags: html, reactjs, fonts

On my react js website, I am using Clan Pro Bold, Clan Pro Medium, etc. But fonts are not working for the Russian language. Can anyone help me with this?

[1]: wrong fonts for the Russian language : https://i.stack.imgur.com/U8MG0.png ,
 [2]: correct fonts for the English language : https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sitzc.png

Comment: Have you checked whether the version of the font you have contains Russian characters at all?

Comment: @Nyubis same fonts work on mobile react native for Russian language

Comment: @Nyubis please reply